# Firebase cloud messaging(FCM) not working on android version below kitkat (4.4)

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-4.3-jelly-bean, android-4.1-jelly-bean

I have implemented FCM as per documentation and it is working perfectly on android versions 4.4(Kitkat) and above and not working on 4.3(Jelly Bean) and below versions. As per FCM documentation it says the minimum version required is 4.0 with play services which I have. FCM is generating refresh token and when I use it to send message from my server or FCM console it is not working. Below is my Manifest entries for FCM.

[Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)

```
     <service android:name=".service.RMFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".service.RMFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have installed Google Services in 4.3 device? Token received on device?

Comment: First try to send message from console when your App is in Background

Comment: I tried sending message when app is in background, foreground from FCM console and from my server but device is not receiving any message.

Comment: Yes, I have , and I'm getting token on all devices including android 4.3.

Comment: My problem is for previous step. Token doesn't generated on devices with mentioned android version! I mean onTokenRefreshed() doesn't get called after install app or clear data. Do you have any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: any solution? i am also facing same problem

Answer (score -1):

Use latest google-services plugin.

In Top-level build.gradle  do changes

```
buildscript {
// ...
dependencies {
  // ...
  // Add the following line:
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'  // Google Services plugin
}
```

}

```
allprojects {
// ...
repositories {
  // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
  google()  // Google's Maven repository
  // ...
}
```

}

In Modual level build.gradle file do changes

```
 // Add the following line to the bottom of the file:
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms:google-services'  // Google Play services Gradle plugin
```